# Operator Overloading = Negation not working as intended

Tags: c++

So I'm working with operator overloading and just realized that my negation operator isn't working as it should be. I'm not exactly sure what I've done wrong.

The .h signature

```
Vector & Vector::operator-()
```

The .cpp implementation

```
Vector & Vector::operator-()
{
pVec[0] = -pVec[0];
pVec[1] = -pVec[1];
pVec[2] = -pVec[2];

return *this;
```

};

Calling:

```
cout << "-Vector E = " << -VecE << (-VecE).Magnitude() << endl << endl;
```

The variables in VecE are like [0, 1 , 1] which means when this is called it should display them as [0, -1, -1] but it's not. So what am I missing?

EDIT: Adding copy constructor and iostream<< overload code:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector & Copy)
{
pVec = new double[3];
if (0 == pVec)
{
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    pVec[0] = Copy.pVec[0];
    pVec[1] = Copy.pVec[1];
    pVec[2] = Copy.pVec[2];
}
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & Out, Vector & RHS)
{
cout.precision(1);
Out << fixed <<  "[ " << RHS.pVec[0] << " " << RHS.pVec[1] << " " << RHS.pVec[2] << " ]" << resetiosflags (ios_base::fixed);
return Out;
};
```

Comment: what is the implementation of the `operator <<(ostream &, Vector &)` ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to return a *copy* of the vector.  The way this is written, the expression `-VecE` will actually *modify* `VecE`!  Since you evaluate `-VecE` twice, you are negating the vector twice, and (of course) the negation of the negation is the original value.

To implement this change, you need to alter the `operator-()` declaration to return a `Vector` instead of a `Vector &`.

For example:

```
Vector Vector::operator-()
{
    Vector copy(*this);

    copy.pVec[0] = -copy.pVec[0];
    copy.pVec[1] = -copy.pVec[1];
    copy.pVec[2] = -copy.pVec[2];

    return copy;
};
```

Comment: I agree, but will it fix the problem at hand?

Comment: It should, yes.  He is evaluating `-VecE` twice in his example code, which is negating the original vector and then negating it a second time, which is effectively a no-op.

Comment: @didierc Note: calling it *twice* is why your answers are wrong. not returning a modified *copy* is the fundamental flaw in the first place, as cdhowie nicely points out here.

Comment: Ah yes, but I was thinking that the `operator <<` would be called first.

Comment: @didierc One would think.  However, my experience has taught me that calling a mutating method twice in one statement is a bad idea, as the compiler will sometimes reorder such calls.  Someone with a better understanding of the C++ standard could probably explain this behavior.

Comment: @didierc: It is unspecified in what order the arguments to functions are evaluated.

Comment: Alright, so altered the code according to what you mentioned however when I ran the debugger it crashed with the error 

"Unhandled exception at 0x00d151dd in Test3 - Overloading Operators.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc"

I had this issue before when I hadn't properly declared my parametrized constructor. However, since we're talking about copy's should I be using that in this instance instead? I have a copy constructor:
pVec = new double[3];
if (0 == pVec)
{
 exit(1);
}
else
{ pVec[0] = Copy.pVec[0];
     pVec[1] = Copy.pVec[1];
  pVec[2] = Copy.pVec[2];
 }
};

Comment: @Rodekki: Do you have a properly implemented copy constructor? I'm guessing you don't.

Comment: @Rodekki: That looks ok to me, except don't bother testing for `new` returning null. It'll throw an exception instead.

Answer (score 0):

cdhowie is right. You are negating twice.

That said, I don't think you need to change the implementation.

```
Vector const NegVecE = -VecE;
cout << "-Vector E = " << NegVecE << NegVecE.Magnitude() << endl << endl;
```

EDIT: As PiotrNycz notes, though this will work, the end state is un-intuitive and therefore the correct solution is to return a copy.

```
{
int i = 3;
int j = -i; //you would expect i to still be 3 here
}
```

Comment: In your example `VecE` is equal to `NegVecE` after `NegVecE = -VecE;` which is very surprising... I strongly believe that `operator -` shall return value not reference....

Comment: That's true. I have edited my answer to indicate as such. Thanks.